# How do I re-create a deleted .gitmodule file?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a submodule in my repo, and I think I inadvertently deleted the `.gitmodules` file.

I don't want to do `git submodule add <git@git:...>` because that will pull the original repo for the submodule into the folder and erase the changes I made to the submodule. So all I want to do is just re-create the `.gitmodules` file.

How do I re-create it?

Answer (score 1):

Was the file committed to the repository? If so, you can probably do something like `git checkout -- .gitmodules` from the root of the repository.

If the `.gitmodules` file was not committed to the repository, you will probably have to rebuild it by hand. Luckily, most of the information that you need can be found in `.git/config`:

```
...
[submodule "vendor/foo"]
        url = https://somesite.tld/user/repository.git
...
```

For each of your submodules, copy this section from `.git/config` into `.gitmodules`. Then add a new line `path` under each section pointing to the location of the module within your repository:

```
...
[submodule "vendor/foo"]
        path = vendor/foo
        url = https://somesite.tld/user/repository.git
...
```

That should get you pretty close to where you were before deleting your `.gitmodules` file. You can verify that you've got it right with `git submodule status`. If your paths are set incorrectly, you will get something like

```
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'vendor/foo'
```

If your `.gitmodules` is set up correctly, you should see something like

```
0123456789abcdef01234567890abcdef0123456 vendor/foo (heads/master)
```

Now that you've got everything sorted out, commit that `.gitmodules` file! It should be part of your repository.

Comment: Got this error: `$ git checkout -- .gitmodules
error: pathspec '.gitmodules' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Comment: What does `git status` show? Does the `.gitmodules` file exist in an earlier commit (perhaps check this with `git log -- .gitmodules` from the root of the repository)?

Comment: That doesn't work. It returns nothing on both my `gh-pages` branch and my `master` branch.

Comment: @marcamillion, I have just updated my answer showing how to manually rebuild your `.gitmodules` file.

Comment: Hey Chris....this is awesome and I got everything to work - i.e. I get the hash when I do `git submodule status`. The issue is when I do regular `git status` I still see my `octopress` folder not added - https://gist.github.com/marcamillion/8ef534feab5be6036b28

Comment: @marcamillion, have you modified `octopress`? If so, you need to commit it *in its directory*, e.g. `cd octopress && git commit ...`. You'll also have to commit changes to `octopress` from your main repository when you're happy with the changes in your submodule. The [`submodule` section of Pro Git](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) would be helpful to read.